# sed - Stop in first space after variable

Tags: sed

A fairly simple dilemma.

How can I modify just the variable with `sed` in a line such as this:

```
_user=Det    # The name of the user
```

to be:

```
_user=ULTRAMONSTER    # The name of the user
```

...instead of whatever's wrong here?

```
$ sed -i "s/_user=.* */_user=ULTRAMONSTER/" script
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this for example:

```
sed -i 's/_user= *[^ ]*/_user=ULTRAMONSTER/' script
```

The problem with `.*` is that it matches everything, including the comment.

Comment: That's cool but with the space in between `*` and `/` it seems to trim the gap between the variable and the comment by one (`sed -i 's/_user= *[^ ]*/_user=ULTRAMONSTER/' script` seems to work fine).

Comment: @Det Yep, removed the space

Comment: K. I'll flag this as the answer when I can.

Comment: Apparently not even the space in bewteen `=` and `*` is required, so just `sed -i 's/_user=*[^ ]*/_user=ULTRAMONSTER/' script` is enough.

Comment: @Det beware that the asterisk is applied to whatever pattern is preceding it, so ` *` meant "any amount of spaces", but `=*` means "any amount of equal signs".

Answer (score 1):

with awk you can do like this

```
awk -F" " '{gsub("_user=.*","_user=ULTRAMONSTER",$1)}1' temp.txt
```